# c# Xamarin Forms implement ASMX Service

Tags: c#, azure, web-services, xamarin.forms, asmx

I have online azure service and managed to use it in my UWP application.

I added service reference, and use it as instance:

```
var service = new ServiceReference1.MyWebService1SoapClient();
var books = await service.GetAllBooks();
```

And in books I get the response.

Now I need to make this to work on my android phone. I have created Xamarin Forms project, and it is working on my phone. But, I am unable to use this service. I have added service as web reference. It is now located in folder WebServices, and named "net.azurewebsites.nameOfMyService".

How to use this service as instance/object? Or is there any better way via HttpClient?

Thanx.

Comment: ASMX and SOAP are really old technologies.  You would be much better off using a REST service.

Comment: Check out the following article https://joshuachini.com/2017/07/13/calling-a-soap-service-from-asp-net-core-or-net-core/